# rename allfiles in python with number

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to rename all the files in the folder with numbers sequentially.I managed to get a list of all the names inside the folder but when I run my loop I get an error

```
import os
from PIL import Image
path = 'E:\\download\\Images\\final'
files = os.listdir(path)
i = 0
j = 0
while True:
    os.rename(path + files[i],"{j}".format(j))
    i += 1
    j += 1
    if i >= len(files):
        break

I get an error:
5 j = 0
      6 while True:
----> 7     os.rename(path + files[i],("{j}".format(j)))
      8     i += 1
      9     j += 1

KeyError: 'j'
```

Comment: `{j}".format(j=j)`? or `{0}".format(j)`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM please post an answer to help others in the future. :)